# Placing image inside Excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3. I am showing some content and chart(chart using jqplot) in a view. Now I want to export the content and chart to excel. I've already done exporting content to excel. Now I want to add image to excel. I've already converted chart to image and assigned as a source to one image in a view. Now is it possible to add that image to excel content from controller by taking that image source and something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use EPPlus library http://epplus.codeplex.com/.

You do not need to convert chart to image and insert it into Excel, you can create chart with this library same as one in your app.

Example of adding image to Excel using EPPlus (this is only example, not full code):

```
using (System.Drawing.Image img = /*...Load image here...*/)
{
if (img != null)
{
    //set row height to accommodate the picture
    ws.Row(currentRow).Height = ExcelHelper.Pixel2RowHeight(pictureHeight + 1);

    //add picture to cell
    ExcelPicture pic = ws.Drawings.AddPicture("PictureUniqueName", img);
    //position picture on desired column
    pic.From.Column = pictureCol - 1;
    pic.From.Row = currentRow - 1;
    pic.From.ColumnOff = ExcelHelper.Pixel2MTU(1);
    pic.From.RowOff = ExcelHelper.Pixel2MTU(1);
    //set picture size to fit inside the cell
    pic.SetSize(pictureWidth, pictureHeight);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i already created charts with jqplot jquery plugin. Now i dont want to start from scratch again. Is it possible to do with existing chart?

Comment: Anyone care what is Excel helper? here it is http://epplus.codeplex.com/discussions/229134

Answer (score 0):

this is how I place image in excel sheet:

```
Excel.Range picPosition = xlSShhh.Cells[2, 15];
Excel.Pictures p = xlSShhh.Pictures(System.Type.Missing) as Excel.Pictures;
Excel.Picture pic = null;
try
{
pic = p.Insert(path + pic_name + ".png", System.Type.Missing);
pic.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue;
pic.ShapeRange.Width = 180;
pic.ShapeRange.Height = 180;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

hope it helps